# Problem installing ubuntu-sdk

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch

While installing sdk this error appears:

```
ubuntu-sdk : Depends: qt5-default but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: qtdeclarative5-particles-plugin but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: qtdeclarative5-qtaudioengine-plugin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10, add the following ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update
```

Or if you're running Ubuntu 13.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update
```

And then run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```